# Need to add cipher suite on Windows 2008 r2

Tags: openssl, tls1.2

There is a .Net application which is running on Windows 2008 r2 which fetches xmls from different web service. This web service's certificate was updated recently and after debugging found the cipher suites used are not being passed by my application.(TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A |       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A are the cipher suites).

**Question1** Can I install cipher suites, looked through online and seems to me that OS has to support the cipher suite.

**Question2** But on Ubuntu seems like openssl package can be updated to include newer cipher suites. Couldn't find anything similar for openssl on windows i.e being able to update cipher suites from openssl. Even if openssl let's me use newer cipher suites can I make use of it in my .net application.

Would like longer explanation if possible or any links which explains the concept well.

Thanks.

Comment: Google search shows there is a tool availble [iis crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Download). I have not used it but the information available it seems like meets your requirement.

Comment: @confusedgenius I did add using iis crypto but the ciphers are not being used in the handshake. Also tried setting suite order still no use.